# Sql Error Must declare the scalar variable , even after declaring variable

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have my query below and getting error `Must declare the scalar variable "@collectionId"`, even if I use `[GetAllProductById] 6,0,0,0,'A122'`

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetAllProductById] 
(
    @collectionId int,
    @GrandId int  ,
    @ParentId int ,
    @ChildId int,
    @dealerid varchar(50) 
)
As
Begin

Declare @sql as varchar(max)
 -- In case dealer is logged in ,then calculate the Discounted amount and return the same,
    -- else return Mrp and Our Price for all other customers

    IF  @collectionid<=0

        BEGIN
            IF @dealerid<>''
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select Top(5) Product.Id,ProdImage,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((Product.BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), 
                                          Discounted = ISNULL((Select (Product.BasicPrice + (ValueAdd -(ValueAdd *(Discount*0.01))))
                                                 From DealerDiscount 
                                                 Where CategoryId = Product.GrandCategoryId AND DealerId='+@dealerid+'),0)
                                    From Product  Where 1=1 ';
                END
             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select Top(5) Id,ProdImage,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), Discounted=0 
                                    From Product
                                    Where 1=1 ';
                END 

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @dealerid<>''
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select  Product.Id,ProdImage,ProductCode,Collections.Name,Collections.Id, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((Product.BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), 
                                          Discounted = ISNULL((Select (Product.BasicPrice + (ValueAdd -(ValueAdd *(Discount*0.01))))
                                                 From DealerDiscount 
                                                 Where CategoryId = Product.GrandCategoryId AND DealerId='+@dealerid+'),0)
                                    FROM    Collections INNER JOIN
                                            Product ON Collections.Id = Product.CollectionId 
                                            where Product.CollectionId=@collectionId   AND 1=1 ';
                END
             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select  Product.Id,ProdImage,Collections.Name,Collections.Id,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), Discounted=0 
                                    FROM    Collections INNER JOIN
                                            Product ON Collections.Id = Product.CollectionId 
                                            where Product.CollectionId=@collectionId AND 1=1 ';
                END 

            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId>0 and @ChildId > 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' Product.ParentCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @ParentId)+' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)+' AND Product.ChitdCategoryId = '+Convert(varchar,@ChildId);
                End
            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId>0 and @ChildId = 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' Product.ParentCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @ParentId)+' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)
                End
            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId=0 and @ChildId = 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)
                End
        END

        exec(@sql)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than concatenating values into the TSQL, you should revise your current code to use `sp_executesql` and *parameters in the generated TSQL*, which avoids the risk of SQL injection in the generated TSQL, and allows query-plan re-use. For example:

```
SET @sql = '    Select Top(5) Product.Id,ProdImage,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((Product.BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), 
                                          Discounted = ISNULL((Select (Product.BasicPrice + (ValueAdd -(ValueAdd *(Discount*0.01))))
                                                 From DealerDiscount 
                                                 Where CategoryId = Product.GrandCategoryId AND DealerId=@dealerid),0)
                                    From Product  Where 1=1 ';
....
if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId>0 and @ChildId = 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' AND Product.ParentCategoryId = @ParentId AND Product.GrandCategoryId = @GrandId '
                End
```

In particular, note that I am not concatenating the current parameter values into the generated SQL.

You then call it as:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@dealerid int, @GrandId int',
                         @dealerid, @GrandId
                      -- ^^^ todo: add every parameter you need
```

The first parameter is the TSQL; the second parameter (`N'@dealerid int, @GrandId int'`) is aliteral that describes the parameters via standard SQL syntax, then we map in the values to use. In this case, for convenience, we are using the same names - but that isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

While building query, you need to append the variable as string rather than just assigning.
Please try:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetAllProductById] 
(
    @collectionId int,
    @GrandId int  ,
    @ParentId int ,
    @ChildId int,
    @dealerid varchar(50) 
)
As
Begin

Declare @sql as varchar(max)
 -- In case dealer is logged in ,then calculate the Discounted amount and return the same,
    -- else return Mrp and Our Price for all other customers

    IF  @collectionid<=0

        BEGIN
            IF @dealerid<>''
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select Top(5) Product.Id,ProdImage,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((Product.BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), 
                                          Discounted = ISNULL((Select (Product.BasicPrice + (ValueAdd -(ValueAdd *(Discount*0.01))))
                                                 From DealerDiscount 
                                                 Where CategoryId = Product.GrandCategoryId AND DealerId='+@dealerid+'),0)
                                    From Product  Where 1=1 ';
                END
             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select Top(5) Id,ProdImage,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), Discounted=0 
                                    From Product
                                    Where 1=1 ';
                END 

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @dealerid<>''
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select  Product.Id,ProdImage,ProductCode,Collections.Name,Collections.Id, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((Product.BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), 
                                          Discounted = ISNULL((Select (Product.BasicPrice + (ValueAdd -(ValueAdd *(Discount*0.01))))
                                                 From DealerDiscount 
                                                 Where CategoryId = Product.GrandCategoryId AND DealerId='+@dealerid+'),0)
                                    FROM    Collections INNER JOIN
                                            Product ON Collections.Id = Product.CollectionId 
                                            where Product.CollectionId='+CAST(NVARCHAR(50), @collectionId)+'   AND 1=1 ';
                END
             ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = '    Select  Product.Id,ProdImage,Collections.Name,Collections.Id,ProductCode, ProductName,MrpPrice, BasicPrice,ValueAdd, Price =ISNULL((BasicPrice + ValueAdd),0), Discounted=0 
                                    FROM    Collections INNER JOIN
                                            Product ON Collections.Id = Product.CollectionId 
                                            where Product.CollectionId='+CAST(NVARCHAR(50), @collectionId)+' AND 1=1 ';
                END 

            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId>0 and @ChildId > 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' Product.ParentCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @ParentId)+' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)+' AND Product.ChitdCategoryId = '+Convert(varchar,@ChildId);
                End
            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId>0 and @ChildId = 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' Product.ParentCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @ParentId)+' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)
                End
            if (@GrandId > 0 and @ParentId=0 and @ChildId = 0 and @collectionId=0)
                Begin
                    Set @sql  = @sql + ' AND Product.GrandCategoryId = '+ Convert(Varchar, @GrandId)
                End
        END

        exec(@sql)

END
```

Comment: IMO, concatenating inputs is *never* a good way to do this, and can (at least, for `[n][var]char`) lead to SQL injection errors. `sp_executesql` would be a much more commendable approach.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for your valuable tip. Stack overflow is a great place to study new things!